# Saving info to iphone Settings through NSUserDefaults (not updating)

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, application-settings

I am new to iOS dev. 
I want to use iPhone's settings for my application to store information. When I try to save the Object 
it does save but when go to the Settings, the Settings does not show any thing but just blank fields.

Here is my code:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *keyUserPassword = [defaults stringForKey:@"password_preference"];
NSString *keyUsername = [defaults stringForKey:@"username_preference"];
if(keyUserPassword == nil || keyUsername == nil || 
    [keyUsername isEqualToString:@""] ||
    [keyUserPassword isEqualToString:@""]) {

    [defaults setObject:@"username_preference" forKey:txtUserName.text];
    [defaults setObject:@"password_preference" forKey:txtPassword.text];

    [defaults synchronize];
```

I am creating a resource in Resource folder where I am setting the above username/password _preference keys.

What could be the reason.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've mixed up the key and the object.

try to change

```
[defaults setObject:@"username_preference" forKey:txtUserName.text];
[defaults setObject:@"password_preference" forKey:txtPassword.text];
```

into

```
[defaults setObject:txtUserName.text forKey:@"username_preference"];
[defaults setObject:txtPassword.text forKey:@"password_preference"];
```